# Web request locks when using GCD and NSData

Tags: ios, httpwebrequest, nsdata, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following code. Any clues why I get deadlocks occasionally? Most of the time it works great and it appears that when wi-fi to 3g transition occur or the app goes inactive and back to live the deadlock happens.

```
-(void) dictionaryFromJSONWithURL: (NSURL *) URL callback: (void (^)(NSDictionary* resp, NSError* error)) block{

#ifdef TX_DEBUG
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
#endif

dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0 ), ^(void){
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL ];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization 
                          JSONObjectWithData:data //1                              
                          options:kNilOptions 
                          error:&error];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(error || !dict) block(nil, error);
        else block(dict, nil);
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you check in your code that the "callback block" you call is not calling the same dictionaryFromJSONWithURL: before exiting? this may lead to the block to be queued twice in the main queue (which is serial) but the first waiting the second to finish (= deadlock).
In any case I agree with the other answer: dispatch_sync on the main queue is source of troubles.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(error || !dict) block(nil, error);
        else block(dict, nil);
    });
```

This **MIGHT** be the problem, you should not dispatch synchronously to the main queue.

The fact that it doesn't always lock intrigues me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, if dispatch_sync to the main queue is not advised, can I dispatch async?

Comment: yes you can. But i really dont know if that will solve your problem